# Why does using Python3 urllib.request.Request cause "connection reset by peer" when url is a localhost vhost?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, urllib

I'm using Devilbox for my local web development work (mostly WordPress related).  I've been working on a Python 3 application that submits to a form on a Devilbox vhost WordPress installation.  This Python script I'm working on makes it easy for me to quickly setup WordPress instances for plugin/theme work.

The problem I'm having is when I connect via urllib.request.Request, I end up with "ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"

Here is the relevant code I'm using to connect:

```
        wp_host = 'http://' + vhost_name + '.loc'

        values = {
            'dbname': vhost_name,
            'uname': 'root',
            'pwd': '',
            'dbhost': database_name + '.loc',
            'prefix': 'wp_'
        }

        install_step_two_url = wp_host + '/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2'
        print('install step two url: ' + install_step_two_url)

        req = urllib.request.Request(url=install_step_two_url,
            data=urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode(),
            headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

I tried adding port 80 after the vhost domain with no avail.  Any help or any tips to point my in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that vhost_name is "foo".

> when I connect ... [I get] ... "Connection reset by peer".

You're not running a webserver that listens for port 80 requests.

Verify with:

```
$ telnet foo.loc http
```

or:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 80; sudo lsof -i :80
```

You will want to point vhost_name at
a valid host that offers HTTP service.

It is possible that your host has two IPs,
say 10.2.3.4 and 127.0.0.1,
and your webserver issued a `bind()` against just one of them.